# Crawl site with infinite scrolling

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl flipkart, but flipkart does not load its page at once. So I'm not able to crawl it. Please help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import MySQLdb
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "https://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/weekend-specials?screen=dynamic&pk=contentTheme%3DLS-Nov-Weekend_widgetType%3DdealCard&wid=4.dealCard.OMU&otracker=hp_omu_Weekend+Specials_1"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

name=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"iUmrbN"})
for i in name:
    print i.text
```

This is not giving any output.

Comment: If the site is loaded by AJAX, you have to replicate the ajax call. Use the browser debugger to trace the AJAX calls.

Comment: How can we do that? Can you give me a short hint of the same?

Comment: You got a short hint already. Your question is far to broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Any link where example of such type is given?

Comment: In the *Network* tab of the browser debugger/developer tools you will see an URL like https://www.flipkart.com/api/3/discover/foz/infiniteData - this is where the data is loaded from by AJAX.